# Undefined index 'invite' error at registration page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am getting this error while simply entering the register page

```
Undefined index: invite
```

But when I enter the same page with

```
url?invite=2000 this error is not shown...
```

The second line of below code shows the error.

```
    $mySess = JFactory::getSession();       
    $_SESSION['fromid'] = $_GET['invite'];
    $fromid = $_SESSION['fromid'];
```

How can i initialize 'invite' if its not used in url...

Comment: [$_GET variable php](http://www.google.hu/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=hu&site=&source=hp&q=PHP+%24_GET+Variable&btnG=Keres%C3%A9s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `isset` function, like so:

```
$mySess = JFactory::getSession();       
$_SESSION['fromid'] = isset($_GET['invite']) ? $_GET['invite'] : '';
$fromid = $_SESSION['fromid'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically Matt's solution but without the complex `if-then-else`-shorthand.

```
$mySess = JFactory::getSession();       

// this value will be used if you did not pass the parameter invite to your script
$inviteDefaultValue = -1;

// isset checks if the variable exists. 
// you can also use array_key_exists("invite", $_GET)
if (isset($_GET['invite']))
{
    // $_GET['invite'] is set, so we can use it
    $_SESSION['fromid'] = $_GET['invite']);
}
else
{
    // $_GET['invite'] is not set, so use your default value here
    $_SESSION['fromid'] = $inviteDefaultValue;
}

$fromid = $_SESSION['fromid'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Terse, perhaps, but I wouldn't say complex. :) Good addition to the possible solutions nonetheless.

Comment: I just figured that a user that doesn't know about `isset` wouldn't also know about the shorthand for conditions. Can't hurt to be sure! :-p